# C# SDL multimonitor performance slow

Tags: c#, winforms, sdl

I've tried following a simple tutorial for using SDL in c#, and tried converting my old winforms app to SDL for performance reasons, but I noticed my code is running slower if the window is stretched across multiple screens - meanwhile if it is only running on one screen, the performance is fine.

The program's logic runs fine with winforms(drawellipse in the onpaint event), so the issue is with SDL itself, or how it acts across multiple monitors.

Any ideas why that could be the case?

**the slowdown ONLY HAPPENS if the window is stretched across MULTIPLE SCREENS at the same time**

changing the refresh rate of the monitors to the same do not help, and it seems to be running faster if the vsync is disabled in the code, but the drawing is still very much stuttering

the issue is nonexistent in my winforms application

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowLong")]
    static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLong")]
    static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetLayeredWindowAttributes(IntPtr hwnd, uint crKey, byte bAlpha, uint dwFlags);

    const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 640;
    const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 480;
    public const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
    public const int WS_EX_LAYERED = 0x80000;
    public const int LWA_ALPHA = 0x2;
    public const int CRCOL = 0x00000000;
    public const int WS_EX_TRANSPARENT = 0x1;
    struct Pont
    {
        public PointF oldp;
        public PointF p;
        public float easing;
        public float diameter;
    }

    const float kp = .05f;
    const float kd = .5f;
    const float ki = .01f;
    const int max = 20;
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double h = 0;
        PointF sumerr = new PointF();
        Pont[] points = new Pont[max];
        for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
        {
            points[i].easing = 0.5f;
            points[i].diameter = 20 - map(i, 0, max, 0, 20);
        }
        if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"There was an issue initilizing  {SDL_GetError()}");
        }
        Rectangle temprekt = Screen.AllScreens.Select(screen => screen.Bounds).Aggregate(Rectangle.Union);
        var window = SDL_CreateWindow("WINDOW", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, temprekt.Width, temprekt.Height, SDL_WindowFlags.SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS);
        if (window == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"There was an issue creating the window. {SDL_GetError()}");
        }
            //Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
        SDL_SetWindowPosition(window, temprekt.X, temprekt.Y);
        SDL_SetWindowAlwaysOnTop(window, SDL_bool.SDL_TRUE);
        SDL_SysWMinfo wmInfo = new SDL_SysWMinfo();
        SDL_VERSION(out wmInfo.version);
        SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(window, ref wmInfo);
        var hwnd = wmInfo.info.win.window;

        int initialStyle = GetWindowLong(hwnd, -20);
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(window, GWL_EXSTYLE) ^ WS_EX_LAYERED | 0x80000 | 0x20);
        SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, CRCOL, 0, WS_EX_TRANSPARENT);


        var renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RendererFlags.SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RendererFlags.SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
        if (renderer == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"There was an issue creating the renderer. {SDL_GetError()}");
        }
        var running = true;
        //SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        while (running)
        {
            while (SDL_PollEvent(out SDL_Event e) == 1)
            {
                switch (e.type)
                {
                    case SDL_EventType.SDL_QUIT:
                        running = false;
                        break;
                }
            }
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
            SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
            PointF temperr = new PointF(Cursor.Position.X - points[0].p.X, Cursor.Position.Y - points[0].p.Y);
            if (Math.Abs(temperr.X) < 0.01)
            {
                sumerr.X = 0;
            }
            if (Math.Abs(temperr.Y) < 0.01)
            {
                sumerr.Y = 0;
            }
            sumerr.X += temperr.X;
            sumerr.Y += temperr.Y;
            PointF de = new PointF(points[0].p.X - points[0].oldp.Y, points[0].p.Y - points[0].oldp.Y);
            PointF P = new PointF(temperr.X * kp, temperr.Y * kp);
            PointF I = new PointF(sumerr.X * ki, sumerr.Y * ki);
            PointF D = new PointF((points[0].p.X - points[0].oldp.X) * kd, (points[0].p.Y - points[0].oldp.Y) * kd);
            points[0].oldp = points[0].p;
            points[0].p = new PointF(points[0].p.X + P.X + I.X + D.X, points[0].p.Y + P.Y + I.Y + D.Y);

            for (int i = 1; i < max; i++)
            {
                float targetx = points[i - 1].p.X;
                float dx = targetx - points[i].p.X;
                points[i].p.X += dx * points[i].easing;
                float targety = points[i - 1].p.Y;
                float dy = targety - points[i].p.Y;
                points[i].p.Y += dy * points[i].easing;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
            {
                byte r, g, b;
                HsvToRgb(h + i, 1, 1, out r, out g, out b);
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, r, g, b, 255);
                SDL_RenderFillCircle(renderer, (int)points[i].p.X, (int)points[i].p.Y, (int)points[i].diameter);
                h += 0.1;
            }
            SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        }

        SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_Quit();

    }
    static void SDL_RenderFillCircle(IntPtr renderer, int x, int y, int radius)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w < radius * 2; w++)
        {
            for (int h = 0; h < radius * 2; h++)
            {
                int dx = radius - w; // horizontal offset
                int dy = radius - h; // vertical offset
                if ((dx * dx + dy * dy) <= (radius * radius))
                {
                    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, x + dx, y + dy);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which part is the bottleneck? If it's `SDL_RenderFillCircle` I see potential speedup fixes for that

Comment: replacing the fillcircle with the built in rectangle is still the same performance, and as i said the program runs fine when it is running on a singlemonitor, the framerate issues only arise in multimonitor mode.

Comment: Could be some DPI awareness issue perhaps.

Comment: What slowdown? Give us some numbers. Are your target performance solely relies on vsync interval? Do both monitors have the same refresh rate?

Comment: they dont, but setting them to the same yields no improvements, disabling vsync in code makes it still stutter the same, the code does seem to run faster, but the perceived frames per sec are still around 15 or so

Comment: I mean if no other limiting factor is in play - it is completely normal to have lower performance when window is bigger as it needs to process more pixels. If you just removed vsync and didn't add anything else to your simulation (i.e. advancing simulation based on actual passed time, not just frame number) - your performance is fluctuating by definition. With vsync it _should_ be capped as your rendering is unlikely to exceed sync interval, but with multiple monitors i'm not sure what actual vsync interval your driver will use.

Comment: To sum it up, add actual measurements to your code - "looks slow" is not a way to go - and either rewrite your animation to use passed time (look `SDL_GetTicks`), or at least add `SDL_Delay` to compensate for frames being processed too quickly.